# Ordering a list Array based upon another list Array

Tags: python

I am not allowed to use the zip function for this problem:

I have two arrays, one of them is a list of apple types and the other is an array referencing the sweetness of each of these apples.

```
names = ['Fuji', 'Honeycrisp', 'Ambrosia', 'Gala', 'Red Delicious', 'Mcintosh', 'Granny Smith']
sweetness = [3, 5, 8, 6, 7, 7.5, 1]
```

`names[0]` and `sweetness[0]` both correspond to Fuji.

I need to put the names of the apples in order using one sorted function throughout and not using a zip function.

Comment: Consider changing the data structure, so it'll make it much easier to sort and display: `[{'Fuji': 3}, {'Honeycrisp': 5}, {'Ambrosia': 8}, ...]`

Comment: `[names[i] for i in sorted(range(len(sweetness)), key=lambda x: sweetness[x])]`

Answer (score 0):

`zip()` is the pythonic way to do this, but you can select the elements without `zip()` like:

#### Code:

```
names = ['Fuji', 'Honeycrisp', 'Ambrosia', 'Gala', 'Red Delicious',
         'Mcintosh', 'Granny Smith']
sweetness = [3, 5, 8, 6, 7, 7.5, 1]

data = sorted((names[i], sweetness[i]) for i in range(len(names)))
```

#### Results:

```
[('Ambrosia', 8), ('Fuji', 3), ('Gala', 6), ('Granny Smith', 1), 
 ('Honeycrisp', 5), ('Mcintosh', 7.5), ('Red Delicious', 7)
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `sweetness` as key, and without using `zip()` as specified:

```
>>> [names[i] for i in sorted(range(len(names)), key=lambda i: sweetness[i])]
['Granny Smith', 'Fuji', 'Honeycrisp', 'Gala', 'Red Delicious', 'Mcintosh', 'Ambrosia']
```